# Salesforce LWC Storybook

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Is it possible to render Lightning Web Components that are built within a project that was spun up using the `sfdx` CLI, in storybook? I have looked everywhere and I cannot seem to find any resource that documents this. Is this something possible? If so, is there any resource that you could share with me that could steer me towards the right direction?

Comment: What is "storybook" in this context?

Comment: This https://storybook.js.org/

Comment: Due to lack of demand, not sure if storybook will ever support loading lwc components. May be you can experiment with adding support in [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/new-frameworks) using [LWR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview) ?